# Shell script to use a list of filenames in a CSV to copy files from one directory to another

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have a list of files that I need to copy.  I want to recursively search a drive and copy those files to a set location if that filename exists in the list.  The list is a text file/

the text file would look something like this:

```
A/ART-FHKFX1.jpg
B/BIG-085M.jpg
B/BIG-085XL.jpg
L/LL-CJFK.jpg
N/NRT-56808EA.jpg
P/PFE-25.10.jpg
P/PFE-7/60.jpg
P/PFE-7L.20.jpg
P/PFE-8.25.jpg
P/PFE-9.15.jpg
P/PFE-D11.1.tiff
P/PFE-D11.1.tiff
P/PFE-D12.2.tiff
P/PFE-D12.2.tiff
```

Comment: Can you give us an idea what the CSV format looks like? Maybe some sample data. Is there one file per line? Are the CSV values directories where that file might exist? Are there the same number of fields in each line?

Comment: Doesn't look like a CSV to me.

Comment: +1 for not really being a CSV file ;->. Please edit your post to show what you expect the resulting copy to look like for the first line of your sample data. Good luck.

Comment: It is a csv, it's just one column

Comment: I don't really understand the format. Does (e.g.) `A/ART-FHKFX1.jpg` mean to search the drive for a folder named `A` that contains a file named `ART-FHKFX1.jpg`, and then copy that file to `/some/externally/defined/path/ART-FHKFX1.jpg`?

Answer (score 2):

using `find` will take a lot of time, try to use `locate` if possible.

what will happen when there's several matches? like searching for foo.bar and having a/foo.bar and also b/foo.bar what would you do in that case?

your csv seems to include a path, given the previous I'll assume those paths are actually valid from where the script is run so in that case just do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read path; do
    cp "$path" "$1"
done
```

then call it like this:

```
teh_script /path/to/destination < csv-file.csv
```